# Using // comment format for Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

**TL;DR:** Where does the JS comment-appending behavior of the VSCode "Editor Hover" box come from and can it be adapted to use `//` comments?

When editing .js/.ts files, VSCode shows a box when the mouse hovers over any reference to a variable (controlled with the `Editor > Hover` settings).

```js
/** I'm a comment */
const someVariable = 'Me';

console.log(someVariable);
```

results in the following when hovering over `someVariable` in the last line:

[image: Screenshot of a variable showing a comment in the hover.]

The comment portion of that box only appears if it is a multi-line comment beginning with two asterisks, one or more lines above a variable, object property, or function, in line with Intellisense's use of JSDoc. Very useful, but some team members prefer to put `//` comments at the end of a short line where a variable was declared. Is there any way to make VSCode take these end-of-line comments into account for variables/properties, or would I have to convert every relevant comment to `/**` to see it like this?

Comment: It seems that its standard to use block comments `/** */` for documentation. See https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html

Comment: Why would you do that ? I don't think this is possible. '//' is already used for comment a line, use it for another purpose may cause trouble. Better keep the standard

Comment: @VLAZ Variables are merely easiest to demo; the most valuable use is keys on objects and TypeScript interfaces, frequently imported into other files. Most of those manage without comments, but there's always a few keys whose minimal distinct description is like "Latest line-to-neutral voltage for conductor 2 in tenths of a volt", or state machine enumerations that need to describe exactly what situation/behavior of an external device a particular number corresponds to.

Answer (score 4):

This 2 minute video was pretty helpful for me to see the advantages of using the jsDoc format. Instead of **Ctrl K Ctrl C** in vscode I'm going to start typing **`/**`** which autocompletes the comments similar to visual studio code typing **`///`** in c# to autogenerate the comments template, etc.  Here's the video:   **[Quickly writing JSDoc comments in JavaScript and TypeScript](https://youtu.be/-gaLriaslpg)**

Comment: Agreed, it is not hard - the question is mostly a workaround to a coding culture.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VSCode keybinding I use:

```json
{
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+/",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "/** ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*\\/\\/\\s*//}$1 */"
    }
  },
}
```

I also use [`prettier-plugin-jsdoc`](https://github.com/hosseinmd/prettier-plugin-jsdoc) to auto-wrap multi-line comments.

---

> Why would you do that ? I don't think this is possible. '//' is already used for comment a line, use it for another purpose may cause trouble. Better keep the standard.

This is silly. Regular comments are used for documenting and explaining code. JSDoc is just a more well-defined commenting format to include richer details. They both serve the same purpose.

But regardless of your feelings on the distinction between them, there is no downside to adding the little "I'm a comment" to the popup in your editor. It's not like the space is taken up by anything else that would have to be ousted. IDE's and extensions should support this.