# Typescript comment parsing for Intellisense only respects JSDoc-style double asterisk comments

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been writing Typescript in VSCode for a long time.  I could swear that back when I started using it, normal JS comments that immediately preceded an identifier (variable, class member, interface, etc) were used as the description of that identifier for Intellisense purposes:

```
// This is a Foo, they're very important
interface Foo {
  x: number;
}

declare const f: Foo;
```

If I write that then mouse over `Foo` on the last line, the tooltip just shows "interface Foo" with no description.  If I change the comment to use JSDoc style `/** This is a Foo */`, the description shows up in Intellisense -- see [this Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAhqAYge3QGlAF0gKYCeA5AE4GgBuBZRCAtgA7pm5IB2uAsAFDRdaAMyQBjShnSgA3n1CgAHgC5QHAK4MARrQDcfAL58+wAFQnQAISRlQAcwK54KAFIBlACLpRoACYFYomTQTLisoCbAfAK4wmKUVjayvPLyRCqamAA2BJx6vIa8fH6imdaUougcsLigQiqSecWlFKAVVTWaKgk6QA), and mouse over Foo and Bar on the last 2 lines.

Am I imagining that this behavior ever worked the way I thought it did?  If not, when (and why) did it change?  Is there an option I can set on the Language Service somewhere that would make it behave the way I want it to?

Comment: A very valid question. Also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370976/using-comment-format-for-intellisense/74353502